# Always running #if debug in dll

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, visual-studio-debugging

I have a property in config named to class like the following in my framework project:

```
public static string PropertyName
{
    get
    {
      #if DEBUG
          return GetValue("TestDevelopment");
      #else
          return GetValue("Test");
      #endif
    }
}
```

I've compiled my project. And I added this config.dll file to different project. But always returning GetValue("TestDevelopment") from this dll. I 've compiled Release mode but it's not working.

What's the problem to be? I hope, could tell...

Comment: You have not compiled it in Release mode (or more correctly, any _non DEBUG_ mode. Try deleting your bin/obj directories and compiling again.

Comment: @Michael Or, more correctly, in a configuration that does not define the `DEBUG` conditional compilation symbol

Comment: Just to add to the useful comments, if anyone is interested, here's more on the `#define` or `/define`: [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compiled the dll as debug, and copied the file to a different one, it'll always be whatever it was when you compiled it.

You'll have to compile it in Release for it to be in release.